# how to model database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm developing a system and I'm having a question in modeling.

I have a table called "Company" and I need store parameters for each company.

All companies must have the same parameters, what can change is the value of each parameter. These parameters are for setting up some system resources.

What is the best way to model?

A)
Company (id, name, ...)
Parameters (id, company_id, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5)

B)
Company (id, name, ...)
Parameters (id, name)
Company_Parameters(company_id, parameters_id, value)

C)
Another. What?

---

Example:

Company A:
logo address: 'http://www.logo.com/logo.jpg'
logon attempts: 3
theme: 'red'
show comments: true
enable notifications: false

Company B:
logo address: 'http://www.logo.com/logo2.jpg'
logon attempts: 1
theme: 'blue'
show comments: false
enable notifications: true

Ps: This examples are fictitious

In the options A:

Company:
(id:1, name:'Company 1', ...)
(id:2, name:'Company 2', ...)

Parameter:
(id:1, company_id:1, logo_address:'http://www.logo.com/logo.jpg', 
logon_attempts:3, theme:'red', show_comments:TRUE, enable_notifications:FALSE)
(id:1, company_id:2, logo_address:'http://www.logo.com/logo2.jpg', logon_attempts:1, theme:'blue', show_comments:FALSE, enable_notifications:TRUE)

In the options B:

Company:
(id:1, name:'Company 1',...)
(id:2, name:'Company 2',...)

Parameter:
(id:1, name: 'Logo Address')
(id:2, name: 'Logon Attempts')
(id:3, name: 'Theme')
(id:4, name: 'Show Comments')
(id:5, name: 'Enable Notifications')

Company_Parameters:
(company_id: 1, parameter_id: 1, value:'http://www.logo.com/logo.jpg' )
(company_id: 1, parameter_id: 2, value:3 )
(company_id: 1, parameter_id: 3, value:'red' )
(company_id: 1, parameter_id: 4, value:TRUE )
(company_id: 1, parameter_id: 5, value:FALSE )
(company_id: 2, parameter_id: 1, value:'http://www.logo.com/logo2.jpg' )
(company_id: 2, parameter_id: 2, value:1 )
(company_id: 2, parameter_id: 3, value:'blue' )
(company_id: 2, parameter_id: 4, value:FALSE )
(company_id: 2, parameter_id: 5, value:TRUE )

Comment: You will have to provide a lot more details than that.  Company could have some parameters directly in the company table, others linked via foreing keys to other tables, others joined via pivot tables.  It all depends on the business need and the constraints you have.  Without more information, this will quickly turn into an opinion and a general discussion on database design, and SO is not the place for that.

Comment: In option A, do you expect multiple rows in `Parameters` for the same company, or is the entry optional? Why have two separate tables?

Answer (score 0):

Option A looks like a relational approach, and is my default choice.

Option B is a questionable approach known as an Entity-Attribute-Value solution. The problem with it is that the domain of `value` in `COMPANY PARAMETERS` depends on the value of `parameters_id`. Some parameter values will require an integer type, some a varchar type. So you'll have a mix of value types in one column, and any query you do will have to take into account the different domains of values in that column. Another problem is when you want to query for companies based on multiple parameters, you'll have to do a number of self-joins, complicating your queries.

Comment: Thanks for your help @reaanb

I edited the question, describing better  my problem and setting an example.

Answer (score 0):

"All companies must have the same parameters, what can change is the value of each parameter."  Then have *one* table, with one column per parameter.

Even if some Company does not have a Theme, or you don't know the Theme yet, you can put a `NULL` in the cell.

I would not use more than, say, 60 columns.  If you had hundreds of columns, consider a JSON string to spell out the miscellany that you don't need to filter on or sort on.  This would also work for 'optional' parameters.